# Rxjs Forkjoin, how do I return single array for a particular property?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I have a fork join that grabs data from 10 http sources, and works well. The structure of each source is the same. However, the results i'm looking for are in the "data" property of the response. I need to get all the results into a single array of objects.

Response

```
{
 data:[stuff],
 included: [stuff],
 version: 1.0
}
```

Code

```
 forkJoin(requestArray).subscribe(results => {
   console.log(results);
 });
```

How can I return the result of this forkjoin, merging all of arrays from in the data property from every response into a single array?

Desired Output

```
[{all-Data-Objects-In-An-Array}, ...]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import "rxjs/add/observable/timer";
import "rxjs/add/operator/do";
import "rxjs/add/operator/take";
import "rxjs/add/operator/share";
import "rxjs/add/operator/shareReplay";
import { forkJoin } from "rxjs/observable/forkJoin";
import { of } from "rxjs/observable/of";
import { tap, map } from "rxjs/operators";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = "Angular 5";
  data1 = {
    data: ["abc"],
    version: 1.0
  };
  data2 = {
    data: ["abc"],
    version: 1.0
  };
  private init$: Observable<any>;

  public ngOnInit() {
    forkJoin(of(this.data1), of(this.data2))
      .pipe(
        map(results => results.reduce((all, itm) => all.concat(itm.data), []))
      )
      .subscribe(results => {
        console.log(results);
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: this doesn't generate a single array, instead it is an array of arrays. 
[ [ {response1Objects} ] , [ {response2Objects} ] ]

I would like all of the response objects in a single array

Answer (score 1):

just add a map operator and run a reduce inside it...

```
forkJoin(requestArray).pipe(
  map(results => results.reduce((all, itm) => all.concat(itm.data), []))
).subscribe(results => {
   console.log(results);
 });
```